# How to find middle point of a line in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 60px width diagonal line, and it follows the mouse cursor. But I want to set my origin point to the middle or the line. Not corner of the line. How can I do that?

I have tried to give a `left:-30px` to line but it doesn't work.

Now my line is;

[image: Now my line code]

What I try to do is

[image: what I try to do]

```
  var originX = $('#origin-point').offset().left + $('#origin-point').outerWidth() / 2;
  var originY = $('#origin-point').offset().top + $('#origin-point').outerHeight() / 2;

  var length = Math.sqrt((event.pageX - originX) * (event.pageX - originX) 
        + (event.pageY - originY) * (event.pageY - originY));

  var angle = 180 / 3.1415 * Math.acos((event.pageY - originY) / length);
  if(event.pageX > originX)
      angle *= -1;
```

My jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/25E8W/403/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed up some of your code for optimization.

First update your transform coordinates as such:

```
#new-link-line {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    -o-transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
}
```

Second, update your linkline `left` CSS position as such:

```
.css('left', offset.left + $(this).outerHeight() / 2 - ($linkLine.width() / 2));
```

This will achieve the desired effect.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25E8W/416/

Full updated JS:

```
// Store this now so you don't have to search DOM for it every time you do mousemove
var $op = $('#origin-point');

$op.mousedown(function() {
    var $linkLine = $('<div id="new-link-line"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var offset = $op.offset();
    $linkLine
        .css('top', offset.top + $(this).outerWidth() / 2)
        .css('left', offset.left + $(this).outerHeight() / 2 - ($linkLine.width() / 2));

    $(document)
        .mousemove(linkMouseMoveEvent)
        .bind('mousedown.link', function(event) {
            if(event.which == 3) {
                endLinkMode();
            }
        })
        .bind('keydown.link', function(event) {
            // ESCAPE key pressed
            if(event.keyCode == 27) {
                endLinkMode();
            }
        });
}); 
function linkMouseMoveEvent(event) {
    var offset = $op.offset();
    if ($('#new-link-line').length > 0) {
        var originX = offset.left + $op.outerWidth() / 2;
        var originY = offset.top + $op.outerHeight() / 2;

        var length = Math.sqrt(
            (event.pageX - originX) * (event.pageX - originX) + 
            (event.pageY - originY) * (event.pageY - originY)
        );

        var angle = 180 / 3.1415 * Math.acos((event.pageY - originY) / length);
        if (event.pageX > originX)
            angle *= -1;

        $('#new-link-line')
            .css('height', length)
            .css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)')
            .css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)')
            .css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)')
            .css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)')
            .css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
    }
}

function endLinkMode() {
    $('#new-link-line').remove();
    $(document).unbind('mousemove.link').unbind('click.link').unbind('keydown.link');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First change the transform-origin of the linkLine like so: **CSS**

```
#new-link-line {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    -o-transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
}
```

Then bind middle of the line to the buttons center by substracting half the width of the line: **JS**

```
$('#origin-point').mousedown(function() {
    var linkLine = $('<div id="new-link-line"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var halfLineWidth = linkLine.width() / 2; // half of line-width
    linkLine
    .css('top', $('#origin-point').offset().top + $('#origin-point').outerWidth() / 2)
    .css('left', $('#origin-point').offset().left + $('#origin-point').outerHeight() / 2 - halfLineWidth); // substract half the line-width

/* rest of code */

});
```

The JS refers to the JS in your fiddle. It's too much to show completely here.

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25E8W/422/).

Comment: ow. @Derek you mean code does not work at all or just that setting middle point thing?

Comment: @Gulhan it was simply off. new one looks like it works.

Comment: @Derek Yeah I had typo `width` instead of `width()`. Thanks.